# How can I disable the textfield area of JSpinner

Tags: java, jtextfield, jspinner

I'm currently having a problem in netbeans where my JSpinner is allowing you to type in the textfield while I only want the arrows to be used.
Is there a way to disable the input of text via properties or some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Disable the JSpinner's JTextField's using the following:

```
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) yourSpinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
```

Comment: Cheers Chris. Works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

```
 JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = ( JSpinner.DefaultEditor ) component.getEditor();
editor.getTextField().setEnabled( true );
editor.getTextField().setEditable( false );
```